# VS2010 C++ Debugging Issues - Advanced Ways to Debug and Application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, mfc

We have a program which is proving difficult to debug. The MFC application runs fine for a few hours but over a day it will crash. Sometimes it will not throw any errors and simply exit the "dlg.DoModal()" section of our code without the user (or any obvious part of the code) closing the dialog. Other times it will crash and throw an error outside of our code and have a horrendous call stack that has nothing to do with our code, it has a lot of calls to system DLLs however.

A bit of background to our problem.

- We are trying to develop a MFC bases C++ application (with a dialog). We have multiple threads and the code is rather large which makes debugging a nightmare. We have been experiencing intermittent crashes that we have been unable to locate the source of so far.

We are well past the use of breakpoints for debugging as we are pretty sure it is an issue somewhere in MFC, maybe not a bug but more a problem with the way we are using MFC.

Now we've tried simple things to help us like:

- Enable all debug exceptions:

  Debug -> Exceptions   and then checking all the boxes so that we can
  trap silly mistakes.

  This proved helpful but we've now corrected all the errors it throws
  within a few hours of running.
- Search for memory leaks

  We then tried Visual Leak Detector (which works beautifully by the
  way) located here: http://vld.codeplex.com/  Our code now reports no
  memory leaks so it is not an obvious memory leak issue. We have
  included vld.h in the very top of our code near the entry point.
- Adding Microsoft Symbol Server to obtain debug symbol files.

  We then tried making our call stacks more human readable by using MS
  Symbol servers shown in these tutorials:
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3f1825e1-6770-48c0-91b0-12d8946ab259/2-how-do-i-configure-visual-studio-to-use-microsoft-symbol-server?forum=vsdebug and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503

  This ultimately did nothing as it still doesn't tell you enough about any errors.
- Using the Thread window to see all call stacks, and using the
  Parallel Stack window

  We have been using the Thread and Parallel stack windows to aid our
  debugging but ultimately they have proved nothing more than pretty
  pictures and fancily formatted call stacks that makes you feel good
  more than anything. We have been using the tutorial here which has
  been very handy
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn

Now for the more interesting things we've tried that do not throw errors straight away but can be detected as problems:

- GDI Objects not being destroyed

  This one is not obvious in VS2010 as an issue. Basically if you use a call like "CDC* pDC = lChild->GetDC();" and do not use the call "ReleaseDC(pDC);" then you have just created a GDI Object that will not be destroyed until your program terminates. VS2010 is a bit dumb in this regard and will keep creating these objects until your program crashes, and the call stack will look horrible and you will probably have no idea why it has crashed.

  To find this issue, start Windows Task Manager -> Click Processes Tab -> Click the View Toolbar item -> Select Columns. Now check Handles, Threads, User Objects, and GDI Objects. Now start your program, find it's process in the list under Image Name, and watch to see if the GDI Objects column keeps growing or stabilizes.
- Objects Not being destroyed

  This is another not so obvious error, if you create a bitmap like this: "reinterpret_cast(LoadImage( GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAPNPR), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0))" and assign it straight to a picture control, the bitmap will not be destroyed if you assign another bitmap to this picture control using similar code. Instead you need to assign the above to a HBITMAP variable which you then need to destroy when you are done.

  This situation can also arise if you create a font or colour in a similar fashion.

Now with all that being said, we have tried all the methods above and we still can't find our issue. Sometimes our program will exit normally and we won't be given any debug info (this is usually after is has been running overnight), other times our program will lockup the PC (tested on multiple PCs), other times it will throw an error but we can't locate the culprit because it simply points to the ".DoModal()" part of our code and the rest is native windows DLLs which is useless for debugging purposes.

We suspect something is either being created and not destroyed properly but we aren't sure what and VS2010 is not telling us anything useful to point us in the right direction.

Does anyone have any ideas? How do we trap errors that aren't obvious to VS2010? Or rather how do we easily trap "GDI leaks" and the like?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

We've been using Microsoft's Application Verifier, it's found a few errors so far. To use it download it here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028  run Application Verifier, add your .exe file in your Debug or Release directories and run the program in VS2010 as normal. VS2010 will break when Application Verifier 'sees' an error. It hasn't found anything too outrageous yet so I assume that we still have issues with our code.

Comment: Do you use COM anywhere? Especially to access a COM server, whose lifetime you may not have much control over (since users can kill such processes in TaskMgr)?

Comment: Tracking down these kind of errors is pretty hard and time-consuming and there's no definitive answer (that I know of) on how to do it. Based on what you wrote, I'd say your program corrupts the heap (in addition to incorrectly managing resources). You can try reading this as a start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx and this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak.aspx

Comment: I can find any refences to "CComModule", "namespace" (apart from STD of course), "CoInitialize", or "#import" so I'm assuming that we don't use COM anywhere. That's not to say that one of our libraries that we are using is not using one. How do we detect/catch if we've lost a COM server?

Comment: Thanks for the info xxbbcc! I'll check out the links and get back to you.

Comment: xxbbcc, your links have pointed me to this application: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028  It turns out that if you run the application verifier and check all the tests, VS2010 will break on any of the selected exceptions. It's already found a few issues with sockets being called before WSA startup was finished. The code still has issues but I feel like I'm getting closer now!

Comment: This could possibly be heap corruption, as the symptoms and cause have no observable connection. App verifier should be flagging this if you have the right settings though. Also, if you're multithreading MFC, make sure you use `AfxBeginThread` instead of the WinApi equivalents.

Comment: Thanks @Roger Rowland. It turns out that one of the threads was indeed having issues. We narrowed it down by trial and error (i.e. disable a thread and see how long the program runs for). We've just disabled the thread permanently since it's not really critical to our application. Still not really sure what the root cause for the thread crashing was but we've certainly learned a lot from the experience. Thanks a lot for the help!